# Looking for byte[] in larger byte[] similar to String's IndexOf()?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

Say I have a large `byte[]` and I'm not only looking to see if, but also where, a smaller `byte[]` is in the larger array. For example:

```
byte[] large = new byte[100];
for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    large[i] = i;
}
byte[] small = new byte[] { 23, 24, 25 };

int loc = large.IndexOf(small); // this is what I want to write
```

I guess I'm asking about looking for a sequence of any type (primitive or otherwise) within a larger sequence.

I faintly remember reading about a specific approach to this in strings, but I don't remember the name of the algorithm. I could easily write some way to do this, but I know there's a good solution and it's on the tip of my tongue. If there's some .Net method that does this, I'll take that too (although I'd still appreciate the name of the searching algorithm for education's sake).

Comment: I think you are thinking of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was reading about before. The name doesn't ring a bell, but the process does. You should put this down as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with LINQ, like this:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, large.Length-1)
    .Cast<int?>()
    .FirstOrDefault(n => large.Skip(n.Value).Take(small.Length).SequenceEqual(small));
if (res != null) {
    Console.Println("Found at {0}", res.Value);
} else {
    Console.Println("Not found");
}
```

The approach is self-explanatory except for the `Cast<int?>` part: you need it to decide between finding the result at the initial location of the `large` array, when zero is returned, and not finding the result at all, when the return is `null`.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ub8mU7).

The complexity of the above is `O(M*N)`, where `M` and `N` are lengths of the `large` and `small` arrays. If the `large` array is very long, and contains a significant number of "almost right" sub-sequences that match long prefixes of `small`, you may be better off implementing an advanced algorithm for searching sequences, such as the [*Knuth–Morris–Pratt (KMP) algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). The KMP algorithm speeds up the search by making an observation that when a mismatch occurs, the `small` sequence contains enough information on how far ahead you can move in the `large` sequence based on where in the small sequence is the first mismatch. A look-up table is prepared for the `small` sequence, and then that table is used throughout the search to decide how to advance the search point. The complexity of KMP is `O(N+M)`. See the Wikipedia article linked above for pseudocode of the KMP algorithm.

Comment: I like the LINQ approach but this is brute forcing and has room for optimization.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Of course it does. However, your run-of-the-mill `IndexOf` is not giving us the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) performance either :)

Comment: THAT! THAT is the exact algorithm I was reading about before! KMP String Searching! LINQ works, but KMP works faster. Imagine if I was looking for a stretch in a large binary file?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Coding a KMP from pseudocode should not be a big deal: it's not one's typical "cinch of an algorithm", but it's no rocket science either. I took a stab at it ([link to my C++ implementation](http://pastebin.com/HD11RYSU)), and managed to do it relatively quickly.

Comment: I can't really mark your comment about KMP as the answer and the LINQ approach isn't quite what I'm looking for as it's a much slower approach. If you submit another answer about KMP, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I added a description of the KMP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of Lambda expressions? That is what came to my mind when you said a more specific approach with strings.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-find

Comment: No, they're very useful but not here. These looks for individual entries in an array that meet certain criteria (at least that's how `Find` works) but what I'm looking for is a sequence of multiple elements in the array.